# Best way to use props passing to multiple children componets

Tags: vue.js, components, parent

I have parent component that contains form component and detail component for created_at and updated_at in editing Product page.

Form is to edit the existing data and detail component will be next to the form.

I didn't have the detail component before so I fetch data from form component and use it in the component however I need some of the data in detail component which is the child of the parent of the form component.

So I moved the fetch axios to parent component and pass the data to both children now.

Is it better to do this way or is it better to send axios request both in form component and detail component?

The form is also used in adding new product.

Comment: Seems like [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide) should fit your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is that you should fire requests from most top level possible. This way your children components (building blocks) can work independently from your current context. It's called presentational component and it's role is to output some markup. The container component feeds the data to the presentational component making the data flow go from top to the bottom nicely.

So in short, you did it right! However you should be careful, when your data changes in the edit form, then you probably want to fire the request on parent again, so that the data is updated for the whole app. This kind of flow is highly facilitated by Vuex. It serves as single source of truth (data) that your whole application can rely on.